# Send apache traffic over VPN only

Tags: linux, vpn, apache-http-server

Is it possible to have an Apache webserver only send web traffic over a VPN?

I've got a webserver (latest Debian) running at Linode that I use for an internal website at my office. For security reasons, I need more than a username and password to ensure no one externally is viewing the site. For now, I am using IP filtering, but my our IP addresses are many and they sometimes change. The other issue is that if an employee is at home and connected to our VPN, their IP address is still blocked because of how our VPN is configured.

I'd rather connect my Linode to our VPN, and make sure the only web requests that it serves are over this VPN.

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it listen only on the private IP of the VPN instead of `Listen *:80` use `Listen privateIP:80`

If you want you can also have sites listening on the public IP and sites on the VPN depending on the settings you use in the virtualhost.